# Hiding/Displaying NSToolbarItem's

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an application with many NSToolbarItems. Only 5 or so are needed at any one time so it seems like the best way to fit them on the screen and make them easy to get to is to hide/display only the NSToolbarItems depending on the context.

I can't find either through google or in the Apple doc's how to do this. Is there a way? (Short of actually writing a custom nstoolbar!)

NB: I am worried this is a little bit "anti" the user interface standards, but I cannot think of a better way to handle large number of buttons that are all needed by the user, except maybe a tool window thingy.

Comment: Oh, and also, I am expecting that an individual organisation will want to completely remove or add buttons to the toolbar depending on their own organisations situation (what they allow the staff to do and not do) so I will have to be adding and removing buttons programatically anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through all the items with `-[NSToolbar items]`, and remove unwanted ones with `-[NSToolbar removeItemAtIndex:]`, Although apple does say this:

> Typically, you should not call this
>   method (`-[NSToolbar removeItemAtIndex:]`); you should let the user
>   reconfigure the toolbar.

Usually you just disable the toolbar items that can't be used in the current context.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I knew I was going to get at least some comments back on the "Usability" of this. The problem is in any given context there are five usable/sensible buttons and more than sixty unusable/nonsensical buttons. (ie imagine one screen you are drawing a car with car components, and another screen you are painting colors on a map, and another screen you are measuring the distances between points on a map. You need all of the buttons but not all at the same time.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off using an NSPanel/NSWindow that changes depending on the context instead of a toolbar. You'd probably want one NSViewController per context, and just switch the window's contentView when the context changes.

Comment: That has given me another idea! There could be a "sub" toolbar that sits inside the top of the drawing area that shows the relevant buttons. (With styling just like the Finder does when your browsing a server, ie the "Connecting... (connect as)" bar)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of endless adding and removing toolbar items in a single `NSToolbar` object to adjust the toolbar for a certain context, you can also work with multiple `NSToolbar` instances, all with their own configuration for a certain context, and assign this to the `toolbar` property of the `NSWindow`.